# Using Complex exponential definitions of sine and cosine, prove $\cos2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

**Question**

Please do not just tell me the answer, please provide helpful hints and hide the answers

Using Complex exponential definitions of sine and cosine, prove $\cos\theta=\cos^2 \theta-\sin^2\theta$

All that I know is the trig identity:

$\cos2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$ or $\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$

Comment: Try De Moivre's formula.

Comment: The body of the question  doesn't match the title.

Comment: Those trig identities mentioned at the end are false. The identities you're likely thinking of are $\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta)=2\cos^2(\theta)-1$.

Comment: @Dave typo fixed

Comment: Well, *use* exponential notation.  $e^{ti}=\cos t +i\sin t $. Try figuring that means $e^{2ti} =e^{ti+ti}= (e^{ti})^2$ implies.  That should do it. (Remember $i^2=-1$

Comment: Another thing, should it be $\cos2\theta $ instead of $\cos\theta $ in the first equation?

Comment: Write ${\cos}^2 \theta - {\sin}^2 \theta$ in terms of the complex exponenial (using the definition), operate and simplify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

> $\cos 2\theta + i \sin 2\theta = e^{2i\theta} =\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^2=(\cos \theta+ i\sin \theta)^2$

Then expand the right side and compare real parts

Answer (score -1):

$\begin{array}{lcl}\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta) & = & e^{2i\theta} \\ & = & (e^{i \theta})^2 \\ & = &  (\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)^2 \\ & = & (\cos\theta)^2+2i\cos θ\sin θ+i^2(\sin θ)^2 \\ & = & (\cos θ)^2+2i\cos θ\sin θ−(\sin θ)^2\end{array}$

Equating real and imaginary parts gives us:

$\begin{array}{lcl}\cos(2θ)  =  (\cosθ)^2−(\sinθ)^2 \\ \sin(2θ)  = 2\cosθ\sinθ \end{array}$

Comment: cos2θ+isin2θ= e^2iθ